# How to add multiple entries to Mongodb document at once using MongoEngine in Flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

How can I add several entries to a document at once in Flask using MongoEngine/Flask-MongoEngine?

I tried to iterate over the dictionary that contains my entries. I simplified the example a bit, but originally the data is a RSS file that my Wordpress spits out and that I parsed via `feedparser`.

But the problem obviously is that I cannot dynamically generate variables that hold my entries before being saved to the database.

Here is what I tried so far.

*How can I add the entries to my MongoDB database in bulk?*

```
# model
class Entry(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True),
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    link = db.StringField(required=True)

# dictionary with entries
e = {'entries': [{'title': u'title1',
                  'link': u'http://www.me.com'
                  },
    {'title': u'title2',
     'link': u'http://www.me.com/link/'
     }
]
}

# multiple entries via views
i = 0
while i<len(e['entries']):
      post[i] = Entry(title=e['entries'][i]['title'], link=e['entries'][i]['title'])
      post[i].save();
      i += 1
```

Edit 1:

I thought about skipping the variables alltogether and translate the dictionary to the form that `mongoengine` can understand.

Because when I create a list manually, I can enter them in bulk into MongoDB:

```
newList = [RSSPost(title="test1", link="http://www.google.de"),
            RSSPost(title="test2", link="http://www.test2.com")]

RSSPost.objects.insert(newList)
```

This works, but I could not translate it completely to my problem.

I tried

```
f = []

for x in e['entries']:
    f.append("insert " + x['link'] + " and " + x['title'])
```

But as you see I could not recreate the list I need.

*How to do it correctly?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143482/multi-document-insert-using-mongoengine-into-mongodb - I will check whether the solution there is applicable.

Comment: I would say it's not a duplicate. The other question does not contain any iterable items, and I could not solve it by the answers provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# dictionary with entries
e = {'entries': [{'title': u'title1',
                  'link': u'http://www.me.com'
                  },
    {'title': u'title2',
     'link': u'http://www.me.com/link/'
     }
]
}
```

How is your data/case different from the examples you posted? As long as I'm not missing something you should be able to instantiate  `Entry` objects like:

```
entries = []
for entry in e['entries']:
    new_entry = Entry(title=entry['title'], link=entry['link'])
    entries.append(new_entry)

Entry.objects.insert(entries)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the missing link between my thoughts and the links provided.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy way:

```
for i in e['entries']:
    new_e = Entry(**i)
    new_e.save()
```